# SQL to capture time periods that a certain condition exists

Tags: sql

I have a table that captures daily data on users.
I want to pull the start and end dates for users when IS_AWESOME = 'Y'
I do not know how to do this using SQL

```
USER_ID     DATE        IS_AWESOME
123         2017-01-01      Y
123         2017-01-02      Y
123         2017-01-03      Y
123         2017-01-04      N
123         2017-01-05      Y
123         2017-01-06      Y
123         2017-01-07      Y
123         2017-01-08      N
123         2017-01-09      Y
123         2017-01-10      Y
123         2017-01-11      N
```

If I use MIN(DATE) and MAX(DATE) I will not get the intervals between those two dates.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Also, could you add the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this uses a difference `row_number()`s (an ANSI-standard function supported by most databases):

```
select user_id, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum_u,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, is_awesome order by date) as seqnum_uia
      from t
     ) t
where is_awesome = 'Y'
group by user_id, is_awesome, (seqnum_u - seqnum_uia) ;
```

Explaining how this works is a bit tricky.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the difference of the row numbers defines each group of sequential values.